# Perl regex: discriminate mandatory and optional characters

Tags: regex, perl

The question is about PERL regular expressions.

I need to match a string that

- starts with `<` and ends with `>`
- must contain number `[0-9]`
- can optionally contain `\s` (i.e. space) and `,`
- any number of characters
- order is random

This pattern does not discriminate between mandatory and optional characters:

```
/<[0-9,\s]+>/
```

and will match:

```
<9>
<9,10>
<9, 10>
```

which is what I want, but also these two that I dont want:

```
< >
<,>
```

So, how to set a PERL regex that will find a match that will always contain `0-9` and can optionally contain `\s,` ?

Comment: Try `/<[0-9,\s]*[0-9][0-9,\s]*>/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to set a PERL regex that will find a match that will always contain `0-9` and can optionally contain `\s,`:

Verbatim for this requirement, you can use this regex:

```
/<[\d,\h]*\d[\d,\h]*>/
```

Which stands for:

- `<`: Match a `<`
- `[\d,\h]*`: Match 0 or more digits or whitespace or comma
- `\d`: Match a digit
- `[\d,\h]*`: Match 0 or more digits or whitespace or comma
- `>`: Match a `>`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8BBUWT/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X90qDu/1). *Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:,\s*\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a `,`, zero or more whitespaces and then one or more digits
- `>` - a `>` char.